# How do I make scrapy ignore or skip a page / link?

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried the following but the those pages are still getting crawled

```
rules = (
          Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=r'/preferences'), follow=False),
          Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=r'/auth'), follow=False),

        )
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried this as a middleware

```
class URLFilterMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        pr
        skip_urls = ['/auth', '/preferences']
        for bad_url in skip_urls:
            if bad_url in request.url:
               return IgnoreRequest()
            else:
               return request
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more code if you expect any help. Probably you can use `from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem` from your `pipelines.py`...

Comment: Sorry but that's all the code I wrote for skipping the urls. I thought everything was supposed to be in rules?